# Is it possible to write any integer $p^n (n\in \mathbb{N})$ in the form $6m\pm 1$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

> Any integer $p^n (n\in \mathbb{N})$ is of the form $6m\pm 1$, where
>   $p$ is odd prime.

Any prime $p>2$ is of the form $6m\pm 1, m\in \mathbb{N}$.
Now, $p^n=(6m+ 1)^n=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n {\binom n r} (6m)^{n-r}=\sum\limits_{r=1}^n {\binom n r}  (6m)^{n-r}+1=6k+ 1$
$p^n=(6m-1)^n=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n (-1)^r {\binom n r} (6m)^{n-r}=\sum\limits_{r=1}^n {\binom n r} (-1)^r (6m)^{n-r}- 1=6k- 1$

Hence $p^n=6k\pm 1$.
Is this procedure correct?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire my question is different from the given link. My question: is it possible to write $p^n$ in the form $6m\pm 1$

Comment: Apologies for reading too fast, I've retracted the close vote.

Comment: Your quote  is true for primes >3 only.

Comment: If you already know congruences (modular arithmetic) then it is clearer to use them vs. Binomial Theorem, i.e. $\large \ \bmod 6\!:\ \,p\equiv \pm1\,\Rightarrow\, p^n\equiv (\pm 1)^n\ \ $

Comment: More generally, all positive integers ($\ge 5$) that are not divisible by either or both of $2$ and $3$ have the form $6m\pm 1$. That includes primes ($p\ge 5$), products of such primes, and powers of such primes.

Answer (score 1):

Minor nitpick - $p=3$ does not work.

Your procedure is correct. However, we can greatly simplify this using mods: for all $p > 3$, we have $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6$, so $p^n \equiv (\pm 1)^n$ which is clearly $1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of argument is correct, but there are some flaws in the technicalities.

- $p>3$
- starting point of summation
- transition from second step to third step is incorrect (should be from $n$ to $n-1$)

A correct proof would be $$p^n=(6m\pm 1)^n=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n {\binom n r} (6m)^{n-r}(\pm1)^r=(\pm1)^n+\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1} {\binom n r} (6m)^{n-r}(\pm1)^r=6k\pm 1$$ where $$k=\frac16\left[\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1} {\binom n r} (6m)^{n-r}(\pm1)^r\right]=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{n-1} {\binom n r}6^{n-r-1}\cdot m^{n-r}(\pm1)^r\in\Bbb Z$$ since $n-r-1\ge0$.